# Get Posts by Custom Taxonomy on Custom Post

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy

I have been trying and struggling to pull in custom posts based on the taxonomy slug 'peers' I am not sure what I am doing wrong!

```
   'coaches_post_type' => [
        'slug'                      => 'coaches',
        'name_plural'               => 'Coaches',
        'name_singular'             => 'Coach',
        'taxonomy_slug'             => 'coaches_category',
        'taxonomy_rewrite'          => 'coaches-category',
        'taxonomy_name_plural'      => 'Coach Categories',
        'taxonomy_name_singular'    => 'Coach Category'
    ],


public static function WhoHTML() {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'coaches',
        'posts_per_page' => '4',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'coaches_category',
                  'field' => 'slug',
                  'terms' => 'peers'
            )
         )
    );

    $coaches = new WP_Query($args);

    foreach ($coaches->posts as $coach) {

        $image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($coach->ID);

        $html .= "<div class='single-coach'>
            <img class='coach-image img-responsive' src='$pluginDirectory/assets/images/square.png' />
            <p class='coach-name'>{$coach->post_title}</p>
        </div>";
    }

    echo $html;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// get the WP_Query object
$query = new WP_Query($args);

// Missed essential point:
// loop through the WP_Query object
// to get the array of distinct posts objects
$coaches = $query->posts;

// each $coach is distinct post object now
foreach( $coaches as $coach ) {
    // echo $coach->ID;
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?